# Running robot framework tests within subdirectories using bash script

Tags: python-3.x, bash, robotframework

I am trying to run robot framework tests within subdirectories using bash script.

In my bash script I have following:

```
#!/bin/bash

robot -d be/output be/be_tests  ## no dirs/subdirs under be_tests 
robot -d fe/output fe/fe_tests  ##  robot scripts within dirs/subdirs under fe_tests

echo Done Running All Tests
```

What I am seeing is:
When I run above bash script with just be_tests, I do see echo statement also getting executed. But when I run this script with fe_tests, echo statement is not getting executed all and script exits after running last robot command without any failure. I need to run bunch of statements after robot command with fe_tests, but I am unable to pass through that although I do see all robot tests under fe_tests getting executed.

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Do `robot -d fe/...` works on command line? how about adding `--loglevel DEBUG:debug` option?

Comment: Do robot tests in fe_tests succeed? It is possible that if tests fail, robot returns error code and bash script exits. Try running with "--nostatusrc" flag or set bash to continue on error, I think it was "set +e"

Comment: Thanks @Pekka, that worked. Yes, fe_tests were executed but some of these tests failed, because of which I believe bash considers that command as failed and exits the script. Adding "set +e" did the trick and I was able to pass this robot command.